# get the current date and use it in a filename

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
mysqldump --user c1bt3 --password=blah c1bt3 > c1bt{date}.sql
```

where date is replaced with the current date, i.e. c1bt5-11-10.sql, and I'm trying to do it from a linux shell script.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the date command with your favourite formating

```
DATE=$(date)
mysqldump --user c1bt3 --password=blah c1bt3 > c1bt${DATE}.sql
```

or use the date formating capailities of your shell, which can vary a bit.

This is ZSH:

```
$ print -P "%D{%H:%M:%S}"
22:30:23
```

Same usage...

```
DATE=$(print -P "%D{%H:%M:%S}")
mysqldump --user c1bt3 --password=blah c1bt3  > c1bt${DATE}.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

e.g.

```
date +%Y%m%d-%H%M
```

Answer (score 3):

A fast way is this, which will give the date as yyy-mm-dd:

```
mysqldump --user c1bt3 --password=blah c1bt3 > c1bt$(date -I).sql
```

If the ordering of the date parts is important, try this:

```
mysqldump --user c1bt3 --password=blah c1bt3 > c1bt$(date +%d-%m-%y).sql
```

(I'm a big fan of Bash and am not very fluent in other shells, so my answer should be treated as Bash-only)